# Customize Toolbar in Electron for MacOS

Tags: macos, electron, nstoolbar

I've been looking in Electron docs about toolbar customization in MacOS. The default toolbar has only the window buttons and the page title, as image below.

This is default toolbar, I'd like to insert some buttons and customize it as it was an NSToolbar in Swift.

[image]

Any Idea would be great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide the default one by passing the prop *titleBarStyle: hidden*

```
const win = new BrowserWindow({ titleBarStyle: 'hidden' })
```

This'll keep the standard window controls (traffic lights) on top of your web-page content.

Then you can "customize" your own toolbar by positioning html-elements where the toolbar should have been.

Make sure to add:

```
#menu-bar {
 ....
... 
-webkit-app-region: drag;
}
```

to your menubar element.

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/frameless-window#hidden
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/frameless-window#windows-control-overlay

or you can look into the custom-electron-titlebar library

https://github.com/AlexTorresSk/custom-electron-titlebar